# Check user settings for push notification in Swift

Tags: ios, notifications

I have push notifications in my app. Whenever the app is launched, I would like to check whether the user has enabled push notification for my application.

I do it this way :

```
let notificationType = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()!.types
if notificationType == UIUserNotificationType.None {
    print("OFF")
} else {
    print("ON")
}
```

If push notifications are disabled by the user, is there any way to activate this from my app?

Or is there any alternative to send user to the push notification settings (Settings - Notifications - AppName)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no way to change settings from the app. But you can lead user to application specific system settings using this code.

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func openAppSettings() {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
    }
}
```

Updated for Swift 3.0

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func openAppSettings() {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
    }
}
```

Updated for iOS 10+ & Swift 5+

```
extension UIApplication {
    @objc class func openAppSettings() {
        shared.open(URL(string: openSettingsURLString)!,
                    options: [:],
                    completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift 3 extension UIApplication {
    class func openAppSettings() {
        let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }
}

Answer (score 15):

## For iOS 10 or higher

Checking if push notifications have been enabled for your app has changed dramatically for Swift 3.  Use this instead of the above examples if you are using Swift 3.

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if(settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
        {
            print("Push authorized")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Push not authorized")
        }
    }
```

Here is Apple's documentation on how to further refine your check: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings/1648391-authorizationstatus

Comment: This is only available for iOS 10+ on other SDKs this code will crash. Please watch out.

Comment: It won't crash, XCcode will produce a compiler error if you don't wrap it/the function in `@available(iOS 10.0, *)`

Answer (score 6):

This is the Swift 3 version where you can check whether notifications are enabled or disabled.

```
let notificationType = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types
    if notificationType?.rawValue == 0 {
        print("Disabled")
    } else {
        print("Enabled")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4** version of **salabaha's** answer

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func openAppSettings() {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: {enabled in
            // ... handle if enabled
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
No, if a user has denied your request for push notifications you cannot ask them again, you should point them to the settings page, you can do this with an alert informing them of the steps and two options "Ok" and "Go to settings", this is where you'd use Roman's code.

Long Answer:
You should only ask the user for push notifications when you absolutely need to AND if you're going to ask it helps to preface with a little view explaining why you want/need to send push notifications, this is a great TechCrunch article that will help you get better retention/acceptance from your users - http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most thorough way, as of iOS12 and Swift 5:

```
 _ = UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        switch settings.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            <#code#>
        case .denied:
            <#code#>
        case .authorized:
            <#code#>
        case .provisional:
            <#code#>
        @unknown default:
            <#fatalError()#>
        }
    }
```