# Programatically navigate to push notification settings of app on Phone

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I have sample app with a button. On click button should be taking the user to push notification service for my app to be able to disable them or enable.
I know how to get to the general setting with this sample code but I think for notification probably you need some additional parameters like bundleId.

**My question is more about URL for push notification for my app not only get to general setup as this is shown on code sample below**

Sample code:

```
@IBAction func pushNotificationSettings(button: UIButton) {
    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
        return
    }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
            })
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this question answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Comment: All answer only talking about getting into general tab but question is how to get to application push notification setting to enable/disable it

Comment: @MarceliJanowski 'You can only open app setting page but not the notification setting page.' found in https://stackoverflow.com/q/35889412/1996294

Answer (score 0):

For IOS 10 or above

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
            // Notifications are allowed
        }
        else {
            // Either denied or notDetermined

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Do you want to change notifications settings?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                if let appSettings = NSURL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }

            let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            }

            alertController.addAction(action1)
            alertController.addAction(action2)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```